# StencilJs set Typo

Tags: stenciljs

I started using Stencil a few weeks ago and I was wondering if there is a way to set a global sass file to handle typo.

I already created a `variables.scss` file under global folder and I also tried with `global.scss` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `globalStyle` config option (see https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#globalstyle).

If you're already using `@stencil/sass` in your project, then you just need to add the config option:

```js
// stencil.config.ts

import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
import { sass } from '@stencil/sass';

export const config: Config {
  namespace: 'app',
  plugins: [sass()],
  // ...
  globalStyle: 'src/global/variables.scss'
};
```

If you want to include multiple files in your global stylesheet, it makes sense to have a file like `src/global/app.scss` and then use `@import` to include other files in there.

Note that this will generate a file `www/build/<namespace>.css` (for the `www` output target) which you will have to include in the head of your `index.html` manually:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
```

Comment: I set everything like you did but I still have a problem with my `global.scss` file.
I tried to change the color of my h5 like this (also tried without the :root)

`@import './variables.scss';

:root{
  h5{
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }
}
`
but still doesn't work. The variables in the scss file work properly.

Comment: If you're using version 1.10 or 1.11, I think there's a bug with sass imports. If your issue doesn't happen without imports (e. g. by placing the variables directly in `global.scss`), you can either downgrade to <=1.9 or wait for 1.12 to be released with the fix.